# Opencart 3 TWIG: how to use AND operator

Tags: twig, opencart-3

I'm trying to use the "AND" operator in TWIG in Opencart 3 and it doesn't work. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I have some product attributes. And I want to make a condition that if two of the attribute with a specific ID are there, then the condition is met.

```
{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
        {% if attribute.attribute_id == 2 and attribute.attribute_id == 3 %}
            First condition
        {% elseif attribute.attribute_id == 2 %}
            Second condition
        {% elseif attribute.attribute_id == 3 %}
            Third condition
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %
```

Here is text example:

```
if there is an attribute with ID equal 2 and an attribute with ID equal 3 then write "Floor/Number of floors". 
if there is an attribute with ID equal 2 only then write "Floor"
if there is an attribute with ID equal 3 only then write "Numbers of floors".
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe in my case another condition is needed. I need the condition to be triggered when there is an attribute with ID 2 and an attribute with ID3. They are not the same, they are different. But it is necessary when both of them are present with any data for this condition to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something can't be both `X` and `Y` at the same time. Furthermore this is something I'd advice you to test in the controller and not in the view.

Anyway if you wanted to do this in the view you will need to track of the found attributes. You could do this with two booleans or just add a counter.

```
{% set cnt = 0 %}
{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
        {% if attribute.attribute_id == 2 or attribute.attribute_id == 3 %}
            {% set cnt = cnt + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% if cnt == 2 %}
    {# do something #}
{% endif %}
```

You can simplify the if by using the test `in`

```
{% if attribute.attribute_id in [2, 3,] %}
```

---

Update of my answer because OP changed the requirements of the question

```
{% set words = [] %}
{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
        {% if attribute.attribute_id == 2  %}
            {% set words = words|merge(['Floor',]) %}
        {% elseif attribute.attribute_id == 3  %}
            {% set words = words|merge(['Numbers of floors',]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% if words|default  %}
    {{ words|join('/') }}
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/zcydg9)

Comment: The first example is not suitable for me because I need to display the text in the conditions.
I have already tried the second exemple with "IN". It works exactly the same as if you use the OR operator in my example. I've added the text example of what I need to get into my question. Please take a look, maybe it will be clearer.

Comment: Yes. It's works. Thank you. Please tell me how to do the same, but now do not use words, but a variable, for example {{ attribute.text }}

Comment: You would still need to store the value of `attribute.text` inside the array `words`, just replace `'Floor'` with `attribute.text`, if those two words are actually inside in `attribute.text`, you just use the `if` with the test `in` and not the `if-elseif`